# Как правильно расположить фоновое изображение в layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть layout в котором 2 колонки с текстом.

[image]

необходимо чтобы фоновое изображение по высоте показывалось в зависимости от количества текста(может быть одна строка, а может быть 5 строк) а не так как сейчас. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

Comment: Назначте фон самому TextView. Так же вам стоит знать, что  ConstraintLayout не предполагает никаких других контейнеров внутри себя, в нем используется одноуровневая верстка. Код в вопросе должен быть размещен форматированным текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: @pavlofff в ConstraintLayout только TextView. TextView несколько, я не могу какому-то из них дать фон. Скриншот чисто для понимания проблемы, код я сам напишу, только прошу подсказать как правильно решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Используете ConstraintLayout или RelativeLayout. Создайте какую-то пусую View которая будет привязана к вашему TextView (или вашим, тогда верхняя граница к верхнему, а нижняя к нижнему TextView). Эта View будет растягиваться вместе с TextView. Вот ей и задайте ваш фон